# why my parsed Double value is not right?

Tags: c#

Im trying to parse a string to a Double.
Here is My code:

```
string a = "10.23";
double b = Double.Parse(a);
```

but b is `1023.0` and I dont know why. I would like to get 10.23 as a Double

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because of your culture settings, you may specify culture for `Parse` method to get desired output:

```
string a = "10.23";
double b = double.Parse(a, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
// b == 10.23
```

Answer (score 9):

In Germany the comma (`,`) is used as the decimal point, whereas most English cultures and your example use the full stop (`.`) as the decimal point. Since `Double.Parse` uses the thread default culture to parse numbers, and the thread default culture is set to German, you're getting the wrong result.

You should instead specify the culture explicitly:

```
using System.Globalization;

string a = "10.23";
double b = Double.Parse(a, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The *invariant* culture uses the full stop as the decimal point, so I suggest you use that instead. Or if you get the string from a source known to be written using a particular cultural convention, use that culture instead.

Answer (score 1):

Or your location for number formatted,  try this my source:

Ext:

```
 public static class Ext
{

    public static double? AsLocaleDouble(this string str)
    {
        var result = double.NaN;
        var format = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat;

        double.TryParse(str, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, format, out result);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Test:

```
  class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var str = "10,23";

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("uz-Cyrl-UZ");
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("uz-Cyrl-UZ");

        Console.WriteLine(str.AsLocaleDouble());

        Console.ReadKey(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I prefer TryParse more than parsing directly. It's elegant solution.